# Matlab: read in part of binary data

Tags: matlab, binary, fread

I have a data set(binary file) which i want to read only the first half of X (and corresponding Y) data which is saved to 4D matrix:

```
 for i = 1:vols
    for j = 1:cols
       XY(i,:,:,j) = fread(fid,[X Y],'int16');
    end
 end
```

How do I modify the above loop so only the first e.g. 10 X data (and corresponding Y) is read in for each vols and cols?

thanks

Comment: Do you file contain only required part of data (e.g. part of matrix) or you need read part of file?

Comment: Need to read part of binary file only (to reduce memory usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement reading for each vols and cols in following order:
read part of Y for the first input X, than skip rest of this line, read part of Y for the second input X, etc.

After reading of requested number of X lines, you will need to skip rest of matrix before read next (vols, cols) pair.

To skip part of matrix you can use fseek function.

Let X_count and Y_cound are dimensions of submatrix; X_total and Y_total are dimension of total matrix. You need something like following:

```
for i = 1:vols
   for j = 1:cols
      for k=1:X_count
          XY(i,k,:,j) = fread(fid,Y_count,'int16');
          fseek(fid,(Y_total-Y_count)*2,'cof');
      end
      fseek(fid,(X_total-X_count)*Y_total*2,'cof');
   end
end
```